# Show/Hide div depending on dropdown select

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a div using jQuery depending on what is selected from the drop down list. For example, if a user selects 'Airplane' from the list, i'd like the hidden div to appear(#number_of_tickets_1). If the user selects car, a different div will appear. Hope this is clear. example of my code below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#number_of_tickets_1').hide();
   $('#travel_method_1').change(function() {
            alert($('#travel_method_1 option:selected').text());
            $('#number_of_tickets_1').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

The code above hides the div and shows it when some one clicks on the dropdown list. I've added an alert in there too. However I would like to show a specific div for each dropdown option selected. Something like in Javascript:

```
if(TRAVELMETHOD1.value == 'Airplane')
{
    NUMBEROFTICKETS1.style.display = 'block';
}       
else
{
    NUMBEROFTICKETS1.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Hope this makes sense. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number_of_tickets_1').hide();
    $('#travel_method_1').change(function () {
        alert($('#travel_method_1 option:selected').text());
        $('#number_of_tickets_1').toggle(this.value == 'Airplane');
    });
});`

Comment: @Arun P Johny, Thank you so much, had a quick test and it looks good.

Comment: Since i already finished it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DoHia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler, with [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number_of_tickets_1').hide();
    $('#travel_method_1').change(function () {
        alert($('#travel_method_1 option:selected').text());
        $('#number_of_tickets_1').toggle(this.value == 'Airplane');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add an attribute to the Option where you have the ID or selector pointing to the section you want to show. Something like this:

```
$('#travel_method_1').change(function () {
    var selected = $('#travel_method_1 option:selected').data("relation-id");

    //Hide all other sections
    $(".sections").hide();

    if (selected) {
        $("#" + selected).show();
    }
});
```

html

```
<select id="travel_method_1">
    <option>Select one</option>
    <option data-relation-id="car">Car</option>
    <option data-relation-id="airplane">Airplane</option>
</select>
<div id="car" class="sections">car</div>
<div id="airplane" class="sections">airplane</div>
```

CSS

```
.sections {
    display: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gxf4/)**

Comment: @ Juan C, Thanks, this example works well for me too.